# How to add background text with a VS Code extension like GitLens?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, gitlens

I'm trying to add background text for an extension I'm creating like how GitLens does. Is there an API, or function I can use to push text onto the editor?

[image]

Comment: most likely it is a decorator with an `:after` content on the last character of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the related source code is here: https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/blob/main/src/annotations/lineAnnotationController.ts.

It uses the decorations feature of the VS Code API- in particular, text editor decorations. See the [`window.createTextEditorDecorationType`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createTextEditorDecorationType) and `editor.setDecorations`
and related functions.